# What countries issues E-visa to Nigerian national?

Tags: nigerian-citizens, e-visas

I will like to know the list of countries with e-visa platform where I could just apply for visa online as a Nigerian.

Comment: Are you really concerned about **all** countries that issue E-Visas? Isn't that a bit too broad?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Maybe not too broad. According to the Wikipedia page linked in the answer below, there is exactly one such country: Kenya.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Nigerian_citizens

Not guaranteed to be up to date, but usually pretty darn close.  Click through the references to Timatic to confirm.